# How to use this jquery function with vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to use this jquery function with vb.net  :

This the function which add the checkbox checked value to textbox......

But i dont know how to use jquery function ?

```
<br>$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    <br>var result = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      <br>return this.id;
    <br>}).get().join(',');

    <br>$('#myTextControl').val(result);
<br>});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$addHandler($get("input:checkbox"), "click");`

Very good tutorials:

- http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx
- http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-jQuery-ASP.NET.aspx
- http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1453-call-server-side-function-using-jquery-asp-net.aspx